# delete specific element in an array of local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have `datas` variable that contains multiple element values.

like this

```
  ["WLP001","WLP002","WLP003","WLP004","WLP022"]
```

Deleting `datas` variable will be possible like this  `localStorage.removeItem("datas");`

But if I have a variable in my js code like this `var item = "WLP022";`

and delete only the `WLP022` inside of that `datas` would it be possible?

[image]

Comment: You have to get `datas` from localstorage then remove required values and set `datas` again.

Comment: yes, it's possible. you need to get the "datas" first and store it in a variable then that's the time you delete the value from array using `.splice` or by even filtering out the list.
Then you just simply store it again to local storage with the new array value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get index of item to delete then just use `splice` to remove that item from array and set your `datas` again in localStorage.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var to_delete = "WLP003"
//var datas = localStorage.getItem('datas');//parse it
//suppose this is data
var datas = ["WLP001", "WLP002", "WLP003", "WLP004", "WLP022"];
var index = datas.indexOf(to_delete);//get index 
datas.splice(index, 1);//remove it
console.log(datas)
localStorage.setItem('datas', JSON.stringify(datas));//set again
```